# How to have an EXPIRE that auto renews when TTL reaches 0

Tags: node.js, redis

I'm building an app where I need to have three scoreboards which I'm implementing with sorted sets and lists. The app is running on node.js using the node_redis (https://github.com/mranney/node_redis) module for the redis client.

The first scoreboard is a 'latest scores' which I'm using a list and `LPUSH` for. The second is an all time high score which I'm using a sorted list for with the `ZADD` command.

I'm having trouble implementing a 'high scores this week'. I was thinking that I should use another sorted list using `ZADD` with an `EXPIRE` set for one week. That all works fine, but after the list has expired for the first time, it'll continue to add to a new list forever.

Is there a redis command to have an expire to auto renew? (I've been searching for an answer for a couple of hours now but the answer appears to be no). I'm coming to the conclusion that I'll need to do this programmatically. During a function call that uses the set, I could check to see if the `TTL` is -1 and reset it there and then. Is this best practice? Am I missing a clever trick somewhere? Do I need to be concerned about the extra database requests?

--EDIT--

I've had a reply to this question on twitter https://twitter.com/redsmin/status/302177241167691777

The suggested solution (if I understand correctly) is to use the `EXPIREAT` command along with each `ZADD`

```
expireat myscoreboard {{timestamp of the end of the week}} 
zadd myscoreboard 1 "one"
```

This "feels" right to me but I'm new to redis so would appreciate some discussion on this technique or any other ways of solving the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you define "one week". There are several ways to use it, for example:

1. "The last 7 days"
2. "Week of the year"
3. "This week starting on sunday and ending on Saturday"

The simplest to implement are 2 & 3.
You specify a set which includes in it's keyname the date/time to start on, using an expire of one week. You then simply determine on the client side which day you want and grab the data.

For example
zadd scoreboard:weekly:03:March:2013 1 "bob"

Then the following week your keyname would be
zadd scoreboard:weekly:10:March:2013 1 "bob"

When you first create the key you set the expires, and that is all. No need to re-set it every time. Pseudocode follows:

if (ttl scoreboard:weekly:03:March:2013) == 0:
  expire scoreboard:weekly:03:March:2013 604800

This way you only set the expiration once, get auto-expiration, and can easily pull the weekly scoreboard.

You could implement a rolling week using the same method but you would need to go to a daily key name and  calculate what keys to get, then merge them. You could do this using zunionstore.